# Material design lite checkbox check property is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, material-design, material-design-lite

I have a checkbox that if checked, will check the other checkbox. I am using material design. The checked property of the material box checkbox in undefined. How do I make the checked property become defined? What am I doing wrong?

[This is the link where the problem happens](http://www.recordspreservation.org/test2.html)

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#exclude_all").change(function(){
    var element_all = document.querySelectorAll('[id="exclude_all"]');
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="exclude_dir_"]');
    for(var i=0, n=elements.length; i<n; i++){
      var element = elements[i];
      if($('#exclude_all').is(":checked")) {
        element.MaterialCheckbox.check();
      } else {
        element.MaterialCheckbox.uncheck();
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.grey-light_blue.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<ol style="padding-left:37px;list-style:none;font-size:12px;">
    <li>
        <label id="label_exclude_all" name="label_exclude_all" class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="exclude_all" style="margin-left:3px;padding-left:31px;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="exclude_all" id="exclude_all" class="mdl-checkbox__input" value="Buscar""">
        <span class="mdl-checkbox__label" style="font-size:12px;color:#757575;">Excluir tudo</span>
        </label>
    </li>

    <li>
        <label name="label_exclude_dir_0" id="label_exclude_dir_0" class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="exclude_dir_0" style="margin-left:3px;padding-left:31px;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="exclude_dir_0" id="exclude_dir_0" class="mdl-checkbox__input" value="Atibaia">
        <span class="mdl-checkbox__label" style="font-size:12px;color:#757575;">Atibaia</span>
        </label>
    </li>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I change this:

```
element.MaterialCheckbox.check();
```

To this:

```
element.parentNode.MaterialCheckbox.check();
```

I guess you need to do for label and not the input checkbox.

All the instructions that I read about material design lite doesn't ever mention that you need to use `parentNode`. Anybody here can explain why?

Marcos

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the Material Design Lite API never seemed to get fully completed before they put it in "limited support" and moved on to [Material Components for the web](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web). You can sift through the [source code for the MDL checkbox](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/tree/mdl-1.x/src/checkbox) to see that the label element is integral to the display and that the MDL checkbox functions need to be called on that element.

Below is a working snippet that targets the elements you need without the extra steps:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // better to add a class to your checkbox labels and update this selector
  const elems = $('[id^=label_exclude_dir_]');
  $('#exclude_all').change(function() {
    const checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    elems.each(function() {
      if (checked) {
        this.MaterialCheckbox.check();
      } else {
        this.MaterialCheckbox.uncheck();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.grey-light_blue.min.css">
    <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ol style="padding-left:37px;list-style:none;font-size:12px;">
      <li>
        <label id="label_exclude_all" name="label_exclude_all" class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="exclude_all" style="margin-left:3px;padding-left:31px;">
          <input type="checkbox" name="exclude_all" id="exclude_all" class="mdl-checkbox__input" value="Buscar">
          <span class="mdl-checkbox__label" style="font-size:12px;color:#757575;">Excluir tudo</span>
        </label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label name="label_exclude_dir_0" id="label_exclude_dir_0" class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="exclude_dir_0" style="margin-left:3px;padding-left:31px;">
          <input type="checkbox" name="exclude_dir_0" id="exclude_dir_0" class="mdl-checkbox__input" value="Atibaia">
          <span class="mdl-checkbox__label" style="font-size:12px;color:#757575;">Atibaia</span>
        </label>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I used your suggestion in my website and it worked.

Comment: I want to Default Tick(checked) same element in document ready. then it is not working
$("#lblchk-Active")[0].MaterialCheckbox.check();

Then I use $("#Active").attr("checked", "checked"); still not wokring

Comment: @Pratik1020 - without seeing your html, I would just be guessing at what is happening. Why not post a question with a snippet that demonstrates the problem you are having?

Answer (score 0):

This is Meterial CheckBox HTML code
How check and UnCheck Using JQuery.

```html
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
   <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="OnAccount">
         <input type="checkbox" id="OnAccount" class="mdl-checkbox__input" />
         <label class="mdl-checkbox__label">On Account</label>
   </label>
</div>
```